# How do I move a pattern swatch once I've applied it to a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, swatches

I want to create patterns/images within an image in Illustrator
E.g. smaller triangles within a large triangle.

I’ve tried to create a swatch with the smaller images and then chosen the larger image and selected draw inside tool but once this has taken effect you can’t move the swatch inside without it moving the larger image, could someone please advise the best way to achieve what I need to do?

Comment: Hi Emma, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I've taken the liberty to copyedit it for clarity. If I ended up butchering it beyond what you intended to ask, feel free to [edit] it again! If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to get yourself up to speed. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 9):

I assume you built a pattern and applied it to an object.

To move a pattern inside an object, select the object using the Selection Tool (V).

Hold Down the grave accent (backtick) key <kbd>`</kbd>, and click and drag on your pattern to move it inside the object.

[image]

Comment: Never knew you could do that!

Comment: Me neither... and I'm desperately trying to figure what could be key-equivalent on my French keyboard...

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, it’s amazing how much there is to know and learn! Thanks!

Comment: @Cai - ah yes, but special thanks must surely go to Adobe for making stuff like this so completely unintuitive.

Comment: @Vinny - there's a pic of a French azerty keyboard with the grave accent on the 7 key. http://www.lehman.edu/faculty/hoffmann/itc/techteach/keyboard/keybfr.gif

Comment: @BillyKerr Nope, not working... As a matter of fact, I did make some research and it appears that Adobe defines it a the "Tilde" key. Apparently tilde and backstick are on the same key on a Qwerty keyboard. Unfortunately on a french keyboard you need to press the Alt key to access those characters. And obviously, result is... duplication :-/ What's more... this question has been asked several times on the Adobe forum without any solution. I'm starting to think French keyboard users are unlikely to be able to use that "Tilde trick". I'll place a bounty on that one ^^

Comment: @Vinny - that must be really annoying. Adobe should fix that. I have no idea why they chose such an obscure key!  The funny thing is, on a qwerty UK Windows keyboard, the backtick (grave) is on a key with `¬¦ but not the tilde, however the Illustrator trick still works with that key even if you hold Fn on laptops, or CTRL.  Perhaps you could try it with another key instead of Alt or perhaps even without the Alt?

Comment: :)  Most often referred to as the `~` Tilde key... same thing though :) If you can hit that key.. this will work for all sorts of transformations, scaling, moving, rotating, etc.

Comment: Vinny, on a french keyboard use ù

Comment: One question @BillyKerr, how did you even find this out?

Answer (score 6):

You can use object transforms (in the *Object → Tranform* menu) to transform only the pattern, just uncheck "Transform Objects" and check "Transform Patterns"...

[image]

You can also use the Transform panel by selecting "Transform Pattern Only" from the panel menu and adjusting values (i.e. to move, just adjust the X and Y values)...

[image]

Comment: Good Gosh! How in the world are we supposed to ever find this out? Why not just add a Center or move capability in the darn swatch palette?