# Put a collage of icons into a shape?

Tags: icon

I am trying to learn how to put a collage of summer icons into the shape of a flip flop like the picture attached. Is there a way to do it without having to place each icon separately? Any tips would be great!

[image: flipflopshape]

Comment: Hi Lindsey, It would be useful if you put what program you use to get an answer.

Comment: One way to do it: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110318/23061

Comment: Very similar question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/104930/23061

Comment: I could swear I put that it was Illustrator CS6, sorry!!

Comment: You could use the scripts mentioned here to do something like that: http://vectorboom.com/load/tips/techniques/how_to_distribute_shapes_within_another_shape_in_illustrator/16-1-0-470

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with help of **Clipping mask**

follow steps:-

1. take **1 shape of filp-flop.**
2. Arrange all summer icons above this layer make all them in **1
   group**.
3. take the **same shape of flip-flop again**. Make sure this shape should
   be on top.
4. select **group of summer icons & top flip-flop layer** -> **right click** ->
   **make clipping mask**.

[image]

Comment: Hello kinjal, the OP seems to be asking how to automatically arrange the objects, not how to make a clipping mask. Do you know how to do that? Right now, this does not answer the question.